# How can I return the name bound to an instance of an object?

Tags: python, object, instance

This question is very simple, and I expect the answer will also be very simple.

Is there a way that I can return the string corresponding to the name I have chosen to bind to an instance of an object? For example, if I have written the following line of code:

```
tesla = Car(fuel='electric')
```

I would like some function `getname()` that I can call roughly as follows:

```
[In] tesla.*getname*()

[Out] 'tesla'
```

`getname` need not be called as a method of the object, I am also happy to call it as:

```
[In] *getname*(tesla)

[Out] 'tesla'
```

I'm sure there must be some function that accomplishes this goal, but I have yet to find it. All I have found relating to the topic is the `__name__` attribute of an object, but this seems to return the name of the class of the object (in this example, `'Car'`), not the name bound to that object in the current environment.

Comment: No, since not all objects have a variable name (and they can have multiple). What would be the instance name of `foo(1,2,{})`?

Comment: So what should the name be when you use `foo = tesla`? Or put the object in a list? `cars = [Car(fuel='diesel'), Car(fuel='petrol')]`.

Comment: Names are *just references*, Python has loads of references. Objects generally don't know nor should much care about what references there are.

Comment: I think I understand the point you are all making.

Names are 'one-way' associations. To get the name bound to an object instance I would have to search through the space of all names, checking in each case whether the associated name was equal to the object, which is an unnatural operation (in a sense, it's meta-logical).